# Garbage Display after installation of ubuntu OS 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Can Anyone help me Im installing Ubuntu 18.04 but after installation and boot up like in the video I have Garbage Display..
installing it n computer server
Dell PowerEdge T130
Intel Xeon Processor 3.0ghz
8gb DDR4
1TB hdd
please help me
I also try to change hard drive
change AHCI  TO RAID and vice versa
I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is garbage display?

Comment: What are you trying to install?  The server system? or a desktop system?  It's unclear; but if you're trying to install the desktop release - does your hardware provide the minimum requirements for Ubuntu Desktop?  (*a huge proportion of servers do not with the inbuilt card as they're not intended for graphical environments*)